# Php converting date format not working

Tags: php, date, format

```
$date = "31/01/2017";
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

For some the above code is not working and giving me the result: $date = 1970-01-01;

When I am fetching date from database and converting in the same manner its working. But not working when i want to convert "d/m/Y" format to "Y-m-d"

I can convert the date in other ways by exploding, but why not the above code is working..??

Comment: You need to use either `m/d/y` with `/` or `d-m-y` with `-`. `strtotime()` expects it that way as `m/d/y` is a US format and `d-m-y` year is many other countries.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry i could not get you..

Comment: You must use `01/31/2017` or `31-01-2017` or see the second answer on the duplicate.

Comment: Basically, when you use `strtotime`, you need to give it a string in one of [these formats that the parser understands](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), and "d/m/Y" isn't in that list.

Comment: If you still want to use `strtotime` rather than `date_create_from_format` as in the duplicate answer, you can just `str_replace` the `/` in `$date` to `-` before using `strtotime`.

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
<?php
$date = "31-01-2017";
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
echo $date;
?>
```

**Output:**

2017-01-31

Comment: your code is working, but why not the date format with "/" one.. The date format "2017-01-31" is getting converted to "31/01/2017" by using the same method..